# Website CSS not loading

Tags: css

Could you please visit https://www.hannahcarolsaunders.com
And go to the about me page via the menu, as you can see the CSS is not loading. Refresh the page and it will load, the same happens to other pages. Comparing the same page with 2 tabs open & inspector it seems the body class, javascript and html lang class change. What is causing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using any pre-made theme than please check your theme options, there should be an option to disable ajax loading of the page, try to disable it and then test.

A possible reason for this is some of javascript which is adding/removing classes are not being executed when you load about page via ajax.

Comment: Thanks, it was a Ajax theme so I installed a different one. It's working now!